# Separating text/text processing using regex

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I have a paragraph that needs to be separated by a certain list of keywords.

Here is the text (a single string):

`"Evaluation Note: Suspected abuse by own mother. Date 3/13/2019 ID: #N/A Contact: Not Specified Name: Cecilia Valore Address: 189 West Moncler Drive  Home Phone: 353 273 400 Additional Information: Please tell me when the mother arrives, we will have a meeting with her next Monday, 3/17/2019 Author: social worker"`

So I want to separate this paragraph based on the variable names using python. "Evaluation Note", "Date","ID","Contact","Name","Address","Home Phone","Additional Information" and "Author" are the variable names. I think using regex seems nice but I don't have a lot of experience in regex.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
import re

regex = r"Evaluation Note(?:\:)? (?P<note>\D+) Date(?:\:)? (?P<date>\D+)
ID(?:\:)? (?P<id>\D+) Contact(?:\:)? (?P<contact>\D+)Name(?:\:)? (? P<name>\D+)"

test_str = "Evaluation Note: Suspected abuse by own mother. Date 3/13/2019
ID: #N/A Contact: Not Specified Name: Cecilia Valore "

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

But doesn't find any patterns.

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow it is expected that you try your best to solve your problem and if you get stuck post your code with a specific question.

Comment: This is a great site where you can put in your text and play with regex expressions: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I just posted my code, can you help me take a look if you have time? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I was using regex101.com but the code I wrote doesn't seem to match the text patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably generate that regex on the fly. So long as the order of the params is fixed.

Here my try at it, it does do the job. The actual regex it is shooting for is something like `Some Key(?P<some_key>.*)Some Other Key(?P<some_other_key>.*)`, and so on.

```py
import re

test_str = r'Evaluation Note: Suspected abuse by own mother. Date 3/13/2019 ID: #N/A Contact: Not Specified Name: Cecilia Valore '
keys = ['Evaluation Note', 'Date', 'ID', 'Contact', 'Name']

def find(keys, string):
    keys = [(key, key.replace(' ', '_')) for key in keys] # spaces aren't valid param names
    pattern = ''.join([f'{key}(?P<{name}>.*)' for key, name in keys]) # generate the actual regex
    for find in re.findall(pattern, test_str):
        for item in find:
            yield item.strip(':').strip() # clean up the result

for find in find(keys, test_str):
    print(find)
```

Which returns:

```
Suspected abuse by own mother.
3/13/2019
#N/A
Not Specified
Cecilia Valore
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pedro!  .* (which means any character right?) is what works for my use case. You are very kind and helpful!

Comment: The cleanup and parameter rename suggestions are also great, thanks!

Comment: `.*` matches any character (`.`) between 0 and unlimited times as many as possible (`*`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **search** to get locations of variables and parse text accordingly. You can customize it easily.

```
import re
en = re.compile('Evaluation Note:').search(text)
print(en.group())
d = re.compile('Date').search(text)
print(text[en.end()+1: d.start()-1])
print(d.group())
i_d = re.compile('ID:').search(text)
print(text[d.end()+1: i_d.start()-1])
print(i_d.group())
c = re.compile('Contact:').search(text)
print(text[i_d.end()+1: c.start()-1])
print(c.group())
n = re.compile('Name:').search(text)
print(text[c.end()+1: n.start()-1])
print(n.group())
ad = re.compile('Address:').search(text)
print(text[n.end()+1: ad.start()-1])
print(ad.group())
p = re.compile('Home Phone:').search(text)
print(text[ad.end()+1: p.start()-1])
print(p.group())
ai = re.compile('Additional Information:').search(text)
print(text[p.end()+1: ai.start()-1])
print(ai.group())
aut = re.compile('Author:').search(text)
print(text[ai.end()+1: aut.start()-1])
print(aut.group())
print(text[aut.end()+1:])
```

this will output:

> Evaluation Note: Suspected abuse by own mother.
>
> Date: 3/13/2019
>
> ID: #N/A
>
> Contact: Not Specified
>
> Name: Cecilia Valore
>
> Address: 189 West Moncler Drive
>
> Home Phone: 353 273 400
>
> Additional Information: Please tell me when the mother arrives, we will have a meeting with her next Monday, 3/17/2019
>
> Author: social worker

I hope this helps